# Speed up php with mysql query (joins vs creating a table at an interval)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website that has about 50,000 people in a database.  To produce my statistics I need to pull data from 3 tables and join them together.  More data comes in daily so the page is getting slower and slower.  I was wondering if it would be possible to create a table that joins all the data I need and then run my php off that table.  It would be great if the table creation could run hourly or some other set internal so that new data is included.  Is this possible and advisable?  Can you point me to some resources?

I am using mysql for the database.

Thanks!

I have 3 tables here - the village level, the resident level, and if they are absent, an absent table with their results.

```
          SELECT EU, sum(TF) as TFsum, sum(TT) as TTsum, sum(KID) as Nkid, 
          sum(ADULT) as Nadult

                    from 
                (select EU, b.name as Person,

                    CASE
                       WHEN b.RIGHT_EYE_TF=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN b.LEFT_EYE_TF=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN c.RIGHT_EYE_TF=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN c.LEFT_EYE_TF=1 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END AS TF,
                    CASE
                       WHEN b.RIGHT_EYE_TT=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN b.LEFT_EYE_TT=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN c.RIGHT_EYE_TT=1 THEN 1
                       WHEN c.LEFT_EYE_TT=1 THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                     END AS TT,

                    CASE
                      WHEN AGE <= 9 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END AS KID,
                    CASE
                      WHEN AGE >= 15 THEN 1
                      ELSE 0
                    END AS ADULT 


                    from 
                    villagedb a LEFT JOIN residentdb b
                    ON
                    a.CLUSTER = b.RES_CLUSTER
                    LEFT JOIN
                    absentdb c
                    on
                    b.RES_HOUSEHOLD_ID=c.RES_HOUSEHOLD_ID AND 
                    b.NAME = c.NAME
                    GROUP BY EU, b.name

                    ) S

                    GROUP BY EU
```

Comment: have you created any indexes?

Comment: No, I read that it was not advisable because the data is changing so often.

Comment: Indexes are a good start. Have you considered creating a View instead of a Table?

Comment: use a MEMORY type temp table to select into perhaps.  But if your primary query is using joins then you should always build indexes on your keys linking your multiple tables even if data changes often you'll see massive speed increases.  I have reports that run across 5+ tables with 2 mill + rows in them and they take less than a second to run on pretty average hardware (xeon e3) using nothing but joins and indexes

Comment: I am not sure it is the size.  I have other reports that don't require the joins and run off a single table and the results are basically instant. I think it is the joins that slow down the result.  So, if all the information was in a single table I think everything would work fine.  Though I am not an expert by any means.

Comment: can u paste the explain of your query here?

Comment: I'm thinking that creating appropriate indexes will solve your problem completely.

Comment: The performance and solution can be affected by which engine your MySQL database is using and how you're using the database. If you're constantly reading from the database while also writing to it, using innodb and transactions may help improve things but if you're writing only occasionally and big loads of data at the time, MyISAM might be the better choice - check which you're using and people will be able to give you more specific answers.

Comment: InnoDB - yeah, we are reading to it and writing to it often.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create statistic on large amount of data, and often, best approach is to do denormalization of data in tables.

In plain English create new tables, populate it with data which you would get from joins, and when you insert data in your old tables, also populate this tables. In this way you will speed up significtly reports. Because joins are not fast, especially with lot of data, having duplicated data is much faster, but you need to work harder at having data in sync all the time.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do but I need to know, is there a way to create a denormalized table on a set interval?

Comment: Not sure that I understand question, can you provide some short example

Comment: I want to create a denormalized table that has all the data I need in 1 table so I won't need any joins.  However, as soon as I create this table it is out of date because new data will arrive.  So, I can create a denormalized table on a regular basis so that it includes new data.

Comment: If you have denormalized tables, that mean that you will have to insert this data in two places at least, update denormalized table and old tables, or if you have some date-time in your original tables which you can use, update data in denormalized table on some period time, and do join only on data in your regular tables after last update time of denormalized db. It isn't easy to keep denormalized tables in sync, but in some cases it is worth it.

Comment: Could I (and I know I am not using the correct terminology) create some sort of procedure that will run every hour that will first delete the query table and then run my select query to produce a query table that I can use to present the results on the site?

Comment: you can do it, but you have to be sure that no new data will be entered during this time, so for example take timestamp in moment you start and only look at data that is at least 1 min old. You need to be careful with this :|

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial for what I am trying to do (ie how to tell mysql to create a table every hour from a specified query)?

Comment: do you have access to server on which this app is running, because if you have cron job should be great solution for this. If you don't have access to cron perhaps you can use this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add indexes
2. Normalize tables (i would suggest reading up on normalization, in order to improve the performance your tables have to be at least in first 3 normal forms and if you further want to normalize it you can use BCNF.

You can create a table out of two tables that have common fields. Instead of joining the tables you would have something like cache table where you select necessary data from.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues here:

- first one already pointed - optimize query and db ( indexes, denormalization, views, stored procedures etc)
- second - display limited results like top 100 only ( pagination let say)